# Hands free auto repeat. Hidden feature or stuck key?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

I have a new MacBook Pro. Twice so far I have pressed a key and removed my hands from the keyboard, yet the key continued to repeat.  Once it was the delete key (<kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd>, the backspace function), and another time it was the <kbd>g</kbd> key.

Just want to know if this was a simple matter of the key getting stuck, or if I accidentally pressed some other key combination that causes this to happen.

Comment: I've had that happen occasionally with multiple different Macs. It's probably not a hidden feature though.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than an exorcist, I'd take it to an Apple Store, because the keys should not repeat unless you let them pressed. There are various factors than can cause this behavior, but if the machine is relatively new, there shouldn't be any reason for this to happen. Most of the ideas come from a Software malfunction, some utility misbehaving or such.

I suggest you create a new user and work a few hours/days from there to see if it happens again. If it never happens, migrate your data to this new account and problem fixed. If it keeps happening, rush it to an appstore and see what happens. It's **not** common. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

known bug on many apple models and recent osx versions (since snow leopard) - fix permissions and if that doesn't help backup your personal stuff and reinstall whole system from fresh. either of those is reported to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the flags, but we generally allow leniency for profanity to exist in the user profile information, but would remove profane expletives from posts and certainly won't tolerate anyone using this name to describe anyone but themselves. If expletives are used to describe someone else or not in a clinical manner that's required by the question, anyone with edit privileges should feel empowered to clean up such language. http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior